# react-native upgrade: version number not specified

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to change a react-native app name. Following a couple of suggestions found here on stackoverflow, I have modified my package.json and changed the "name" with my new app name. Then I ran this commad:

```
react-native upgrade
```

I get this error:

[image]

**A valid version number for 'react-native' is not spedified**

How do I solve this error?

Thanks

Comment: What is the react-native version defined under dependencies in your package.json? (e.g. `"react-native": "0.40.0"`)

Comment: It is version 0.39

Comment: Can you change it to 0.39.0?

Comment: Thanks, I did. Now I get this message:
react-native version in package.json doesn't match the installed version in node_modules. Try running npm install to fix this. Aborting

Comment: Can you run 'react-native --version' to get what is the current installed version then change to that accordingly in the package.json.

Comment: It has worked. After having run npm install, react-native upgrade ran successfully. And the app name has changed. Thanks